# Update a variable in a mysql table depending on a time difference

Tags: mysql, sql, time, sql-update, difference

**CONTEXT**

I would like to update a variable inside a table depending on a time difference.

**DATA**

I have the following mySQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE `userTP` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profile` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `inprogress` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `launchedat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `npoints` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
  `ms` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5000'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `userTP` (`id`, `profile`, `username`, `inprogress`, `launchedat`, `password`, `npoints`, `ms`) VALUES
(4, 0, 'binome1', 1, '2020-11-10 17:20:07', 'vvvvv', 10, 1000),
(48, 0, 'binome2', 0, '2020-06-11 14:45:07', 'llll', 10, 1000);


ALTER TABLE `userTP`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `userTP`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=49;
COMMIT;
```

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO**

If the time difference between `launchedat` and the current time is larger than 10 minutes, I would like to update the variable `inprogress` and set it to 2 for user with `id` 4

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
UPDATE userTP SET inprogress = '2' WHERE ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(launchedat,NOW()))/60)>10  AND id = 4
```

This gives no error but does not work .....
Any Idea ?

Comment: You have the arguments to `timediff()` in the wrong order. The later time should be first.

Comment: I have spent 2hours for this stupid mistake. THANKS